# How to deploy an EIP1167 proxy contract from an EOA's transaction

Tags: raw-transaction, eip-1167

I have seen a number of examples where people deploy proxies with other contracts. For example, [here](https://medium.com/coinmonks/diving-into-smart-contracts-minimal-proxy-eip-1167-3c4e7f1a41b8).

Where can I read / see an example of how to construct and send an EOA's transaction to deploy a minimal proxy?

Answer (score 0):

every proxy(and its derivatives) are just smart contracts. and there are various tools/libraries available to construct and interact with contracts.

for starters: you can use [remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/) (which is a powerful open source tool that helps you write Solidity contracts straight from the browser)

for more proxy based examples you can use [this](https://ethereum-blockchain-developer.com/110-upgrade-smart-contracts/05-proxy-nick-johnson/) - the entire guide in general is a good place to start as well